# is an apple developer account needed to connect to firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, initialization

I've been trying to run my flutter app that connects to the fire store and initialize the fire base connection but I've been running into issues where the initialization always errors out.

In one of the tutorials on YouTube I saw that We need an Apple developer account added to the runner workspace.

Is it really not possible to connect to the fire store without an Apple developer account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use an Apple developer account during development of any of my iOS code, and can run it fine on the iOS simulator. So: no, a developer account is not needed to connect to Firestore.